# Merge objects with with missing key

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have two objects like that:

```
const object1 = {first: [{timestamp: "2018-12-09T16:00:00.000", count: 3}], second: [{timestamp: "2018-12-09T17:00:00.000", count: 2}], third: [{timestamp: "2018-12-09T18:00:00.000", count: 2}]}
const object2 = {first: [{timestamp: "2018-12-09T16:00:00.000", count: 0}], second: [{timestamp: "2018-12-09T17:00:00.000", count: 0}], third: [{timestamp: "2018-12-09T18:00:00.000", count: 3}]}
```

(`object1` and `object2` could have array of lenght > 1, for example:

```
const object1 = {first: [{timestamp: "2018-12-09T16:00:00.000", count: 3}, {timestamp: "2018-12-09T16:30:00.000", count: 5}], second: [{timestamp: "2018-12-09T17:00:00.000", count: 2}], third: [{timestamp: "2018-12-09T18:00:00.000", count: 2}]}
const object2 = {first: [{timestamp: "2018-12-09T16:00:00.000", count: 0}, {timestamp: "2018-12-09T16:30:00.000", count: 0}], second: [{timestamp: "2018-12-09T17:00:00.000", count: 0}], third: [{timestamp: "2018-12-09T18:00:00.000", count: 3}]}
```

)

and I want an object of the same format but:

- the value of key `timestamp` should be a real data not a string (so I need to do `new Data(timestamp)`)
- the value of key `count` should be the sum

So the expected result is:

```
const res = {first: [{timestamp: 2018-12-09T16:00:00.000, count: 3}], second: [{timestamp: 2018-12-09T17:00:00.000, count: 2}], third: [{timestamp: 2018-12-09T18:00:00.000, count: 5}]}
```

( if `object1` and `object2` have array of length > 1:

```
const res = {first: [{timestamp: 2018-12-09T16:00:00.000, count: 3}, {timestamp: "2018-12-09T16:30:00.000", count: 5}], second: [{timestamp: 2018-12-09T17:00:00.000, count: 2}], third: [{timestamp: 2018-12-09T18:00:00.000, count: 5}]}
```

)

I used `mergeWith` of Lodash in this way:

```
const merged = _.mergeWith(object1, object2, (objValue, srcValue) => [
  { count: objValue[0].count + srcValue[0].count },
])
const r = Object.entries(merged).map(([key, value], i) => {
  return { number: key, timestamp: value.map(convertTimestamp) }
})
console.log('r: ', r)
```

where `convertTimestamp` is:

```
const convertTimestamp = (d) => ({
  ...d,
  timestamp: new Date(d.timestamp),
})
```

This is the result:

```
[
  {
    "number": "first",
    "timestamp": [
      {
        "count": 3,
        "timestamp": null
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "number": "second",
    "timestamp": [
      {
        "count": 2,
        "timestamp": null
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "number": "third",
    "timestamp": [
      {
        "count": 5,
        "timestamp": null
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Obviously it doesnt' work.
It has 3 problems:

1. nested object with no correct values
2. timestamp is not correct
3. if `object1` and `object2` have the same key but If they are:

`const object1 = {first: [{timestamp: "2018-12-09T16:00:00.000", count: 3}], second: [{timestamp: "2018-12-09T17:00:00.000", count: 2}], third: [{timestamp: "2018-12-09T18:00:00.000", count: 2}]}`

`const object2 = {second: [{timestamp: "2018-12-09T17:00:00.000", count: 0}], third: [{timestamp: "2018-12-09T18:00:00.000", count: 3}]}`

(object2 is missing `first`), that procedure doesn't work...

I need help

Here a testable code:

```js
function mergeData(object1, object2) {
  const merged = _.mergeWith(object1, object2, (objValue, srcValue) => [
    { count: objValue[0].count + srcValue[0].count},
  ])
  const r = Object.entries(merged).map(([key, value], i) => {
    return { number: key, timestamp: value.map(convertTimestamp) }
  })
  return r
}

const convertTimestamp = (d) => {
  return ({
    ...d,
    timestamp: new Date(d.timestamp),
  })
}

const object1 = {first: [{timestamp: "2018-12-09T16:00:00.000", count: 3}], second: [{timestamp: "2018-12-09T17:00:00.000", count: 2}], third: [{timestamp: "2018-12-09T18:00:00.000", count: 2}]}
const object2 = {first: [{timestamp: "2018-12-09T16:00:00.000", count: 0}], second: [{timestamp: "2018-12-09T17:00:00.000", count: 0}], third: [{timestamp: "2018-12-09T18:00:00.000", count: 3}]}


const result = mergeData(object1, object2)
console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

---

Some examples:

```
// example 1
const object1 = {
  first: [{timestamp: "2018-12-09T16:00:00.000", count: 3}, {timestamp: "2018-12-09T16:30:00.000", count: 5}], 
  second: [{timestamp: "2018-12-09T17:00:00.000", count: 2}], 
  third: [{timestamp: "2018-12-09T18:00:00.000", count: 2}]
}
const object2 = {
  first: [{timestamp: "2018-12-09T16:00:00.000", count: 0}, {timestamp: "2018-12-09T16:30:00.000", count: 0}], 
  second: [{timestamp: "2018-12-09T17:00:00.000", count: 0}], 
  third: [{timestamp: "2018-12-09T18:00:00.000", count: 3}]
}

const result = {
  first: [{timestamp: "2018-12-09T16:00:00.000", count: 3}, {timestamp: "2018-12-09T16:30:00.000", count: 5}], 
  second: [{timestamp: "2018-12-09T17:00:00.000", count: 2}], 
  third: [{timestamp: "2018-12-09T18:00:00.000", count: 5}]
}


// example 2
const object1 = {
  first: [{timestamp: "2018-12-09T16:00:00.000", count: 3}, {timestamp: "2018-12-09T16:30:00.000", count: 5}], 
  second: [{timestamp: "2018-12-09T17:00:00.000", count: 2}], 
  third: [{timestamp: "2018-12-09T18:00:00.000", count: 2}]
}
const object2 = {
  first: [{timestamp: "2018-12-09T16:00:00.000", count: 0}], 
  second: [{timestamp: "2018-12-09T17:00:00.000", count: 0}], 
  third: [{timestamp: "2018-12-09T18:00:00.000", count: 3}]
}

const result = {
  first: [{timestamp: "2018-12-09T16:00:00.000", count: 3}, {timestamp: "2018-12-09T16:30:00.000", count: 5}], 
  second: [{timestamp: "2018-12-09T17:00:00.000", count: 2}], 
  third: [{timestamp: "2018-12-09T18:00:00.000", count: 5}]
}


// example 3
const object1 = {
  first: [{timestamp: "2018-12-09T16:00:00.000", count: 3}, {timestamp: "2018-12-09T16:30:00.000", count: 5}], 
  second: [{timestamp: "2018-12-09T17:00:00.000", count: 2}], 
  third: [{timestamp: "2018-12-09T18:00:00.000", count: 2}]
}
const object2 = {
  second: [{timestamp: "2018-12-09T17:00:00.000", count: 0}], 
  third: [{timestamp: "2018-12-09T18:00:00.000", count: 3}]
}

const result = {
  first: [{timestamp: "2018-12-09T16:00:00.000", count: 3}, {timestamp: "2018-12-09T16:30:00.000", count: 5}], 
  second: [{timestamp: "2018-12-09T17:00:00.000", count: 2}], 
  third: [{timestamp: "2018-12-09T18:00:00.000", count: 5}]
}


// example 4
const object1 = {
  first: [{timestamp: "2018-12-09T16:00:00.000", count: 3}, {timestamp: "2018-12-09T16:30:00.000", count: 5}], 
  second: [{timestamp: "2018-12-09T17:00:00.000", count: 2}, {timestamp: "2018-12-09T17:30:00.000", count: 20}, {timestamp: "2018-12-09T18:00:00.000", count: 10}], 
  third: [{timestamp: "2018-12-09T18:00:00.000", count: 2}]
}
const object2 = {
  first: [{timestamp: "2018-12-09T16:00:00.000", count: 0}, {timestamp: "2018-12-09T16:30:00.000", count: 0}], 
  second: [{timestamp: "2018-12-09T17:00:00.000", count: 0}, {timestamp: "2018-12-09T17:30:00.000", count: 6}, {timestamp: "2018-12-09T18:00:00.000", count: 2}], 
  third: [{timestamp: "2018-12-09T18:00:00.000", count: 3}]
}

const result = {
  first: [{timestamp: "2018-12-09T16:00:00.000", count: 3}, {timestamp: "2018-12-09T16:30:00.000", count: 5}], 
  second: [{timestamp: "2018-12-09T17:00:00.000", count: 2}, {timestamp: "2018-12-09T17:30:00.000", count: 26}, {timestamp: "2018-12-09T18:00:00.000", count: 12}], 
  third: [{timestamp: "2018-12-09T18:00:00.000", count: 5}]
}
```

Comment: Your `first`, `second` and `third` are arrays with 1 element. What's the reason of this?

Comment: @KoshVery for semplicity in this example but they could have more than 1 element

Comment: Well, how should they be merged then?

Comment: @KoshVery I added an example in my code about that

Comment: If `object1` and `object2` both have `first` property present, then which timestamp should be there in `result.first`?

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj Hi Mohit, there be the array with the sum of the key `count`

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj I added some example

Comment: @KoshVery I added some example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lodash's `_.mergeWith()` callback gets the keys as the 3rd param. You can use it to decide how to merge the items:

```js
const object1 = {first: [{timestamp: "2018-12-09T16:00:00.000", count: 3}], second: [{timestamp: "2018-12-09T17:00:00.000", count: 2}], third: [{timestamp: "2018-12-09T18:00:00.000", count: 2}]}
const object2 = {first: [{timestamp: "2018-12-09T16:00:00.000", count: 0}], second: [{timestamp: "2018-12-09T17:00:00.000", count: 0}], third: [{timestamp: "2018-12-09T18:00:00.000", count: 3}]}

const mergefn = (...args) =>
  _.mergeWith({}, ...args, (o, s, k) => {
      if(_.eq(k, 'timestamp')) return new Date(s);
      if(_.eq(k, 'count')) return (o || 0) + s;
  });
  
const result = mergefn(object1, object2);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

So what mergeWith is doing it is applying the customizer recursively, so what you wanna do is to check what type it is, like `typeof(a) == 'string'`, if you will have another typeof string data in objects you would have to add more complex logic to that to ensure that you are merging strings with proper date format using regex.

```js
const object1 = {first: [{timestamp: "2018-12-09T16:00:00.000", count: 3}], second: [{timestamp: "2018-12-09T17:00:00.000", count: 2}], third: [{timestamp: "2018-12-09T18:00:00.000", count: 2}]}
const object2 = {first: [{timestamp: "2018-12-09T16:00:00.000", count: 0}], second: [{timestamp: "2018-12-09T17:00:00.000", count: 0}], third: [{timestamp: "2018-12-09T18:00:00.000", count: 3}]}

function mergeData(a,b){
    return _.mergeWith(a,b, (a,b)=>{
        if(typeof(a) == "string") return new Date(a);
        if(typeof(a) == "number") return a+b;
    });
}
console.log(mergeData(object1, object2));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have this via [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [`Array.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)  in **ES6**:

`Note in the example I have extra objects in "first" array for tesitng purposes`

```js
const o1 = {first: [{timestamp: "2018-12-09T16:00:00.000", count: 3},{timestamp: "2019-12-09T16:00:00.000", count: 1}], second: [{timestamp: "2018-12-09T17:00:00.000", count: 2}], third: [{timestamp: "2018-12-09T18:00:00.000", count: 2}]}
const o2 = {first: [{timestamp: "2018-12-09T16:00:00.000", count: 0}, {timestamp: "2019-12-09T16:00:00.000", count: 11}], second: [{timestamp: "2018-12-09T17:00:00.000", count: 0}], third: [{timestamp: "2018-12-09T18:00:00.000", count: 3}]}

const groupObjects = arr => arr.reduce((r,c) => {
  Object.entries(c).forEach(([k,v]) => {
    let key = `${k}`
    r[key] = r[key] || []
    v.forEach(({timestamp, count}, i) => {
      r[key][i] = r[key][i] || ({timestamp: new Date(timestamp), count: 0})
      r[key][i].count += count
    })
  })
  return r
}, {})

console.log(groupObjects([o1, o2]))
```

The only tricky thing is that you need to group on the object key `first` and then do the 2nd forEach to get the values summed.

**This is assuming that `object1` and `object2` always have the same arrays length**.

Comment: thanks for your reply but array value of key `first`, `second`, `third` could have more than one object..

Comment: Updated with the handling of multiple objects in `first` etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably easier from a readability standpoint to break this down into smaller problems. For example, you need to be able to merge the subarray on date and you also need to be prepared for different sets of keys in each object.

This tackles each one:

```js
const object1 = {first: [{timestamp: "2018-12-09T16:00:00.000", count: 3}], second: [{timestamp: "2018-12-09T17:00:00.000", count: 2}], third: [{timestamp: "2018-12-09T18:00:00.000", count: 2}]}
const object2 = {first: [{timestamp: "2018-12-09T16:00:00.000", count: 0}], second: [{timestamp: "2018-12-09T17:00:00.000", count: 0}], third: [{timestamp: "2018-12-09T18:00:00.000", count: 3}]}

// a function to merge arrays with defaulf values
// in  case one is not defined
function mergeArray(a1 =[], a2 =[]){
    let hash  = [...a1, ...a2].reduce((hash, {timestamp, count}) =>{
        if(!hash.hasOwnProperty(timestamp)) hash[timestamp] = {timestamp, count:0}
        hash[timestamp].count += count
        return hash
    }, {})
    return Object.values(hash)
}

// a set of all keys between the tow objects
// so the objects don't nees to have the same keys
// we'll loop over this to make sure we get everything
const allKeys = new Set([...Object.keys(object1), ...Object.keys(object2)])

// now for each known key merge the arrays
let res = {}
for (key of allKeys){
    res[key] = mergeArray(object1[key], object2[key])
}
console.log(res)
```